# Configurar Nginx para múltiplos servidores Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

A ideia aqui é descentralizar, fazer um **load balancing**.

No seguinte cenário:

.1 um website servindo múltiplos subdomínios com `Nginx`

.2 dois ou mais servidores `nodejs` rodando `socket.io`

Minha necessidade com `nodejs` é manter um servidor para mensagens e outros para por exemplo: propagandas, aplicativos, ferramentas.

A maioria dos canais que procurei respostas me disse que o negocio é manter tudo em um só **o.O** ? Mas se houver algum erro fatal em **ferramentas** por exemplo vai acabar derrubando tudo (apps, ads, chat).

Oficialmente Socket.IO não ajuda muito e sua documentação [using-multiple-nodes](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) e o mais próximo que cheguei a ter um entendimento foi através deste tutorial [deploy-multiple-node-js-socket-io-servers-with-nginx-and-ssl](https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2015/07/20/how-to-deploy-multiple-node-js-socket-io-servers-with-nginx-and-ssl/).

Mas embora a ideia seja **descentralizar** mesmo assim eu ainda preciso que `socket.io` ou os **sockets** se baseiem no ponto de origem neste case uma **rom** especifica.

Li em algumas resenhas que isso podia ser feito com `Redis` porém `Redis` não é uma alternativa para mim pois estou usando `MongoDB` dai então achei isso: [socket.io-mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-mongodb) que faz a mesma coisa que o faria com `Redis`.

Seguindo esta lógica qualquer página `HTML` precisaria ler o `javascript` de `socket.io` (independente do servidor do socket) ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost:9000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

E no `javascript` das paginas eu teria algo como:

```
//para mensagens
var msg = io.connect('//localhost:9000');

// para o servidor de propagandas
var ads = io.connect('//localhost:7001');

// para o servidor de ferramentas
var tool = io.connect('//localhost:8001');
```

Comment: Tu quer loading balancing mesmo ou apenas apontar cada subdomínio para uma app nodejs? Tu pode usar o nginx como proxy para suas apps. Daí cada app node vai rodar em uma porta e tu configura nginx para apontar o subdomínio para a porta correta.

Comment: @George Moura não quero fazer proxy para subdominios já tenho server blocks para isso, o que eu quero é fazer um loading balancing para as requisições aos sockets servers pois eles podem ser chamados de qualquer subdominio entendes?

Comment: Veja se este link pode lhe ajudar: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing

Comment: @GeorgeMoura o link foi de grande ajuda era isso mesmo balancear a carga entre multiplos  sockets. se puderes add uma resposta dentro do contexto de minha pergunta para ficar de referencia e para aceitação. grato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pode usar o módulo de upstream do nginx e fazer algo como isso:

`upstream backend  {
  server backend1.example.com;
  server backend2.example.com;
  server backend3.example.com;
}`

e depois referenciar no server

`server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
  }
}`

Para mais detalhes veja este tutorial da digital ocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing